# CSS variable gets overridden by itself?

Tags: css, angular, sass, scss-mixins

I have created a mixin for angular theming like so:

```
@mixin generate-theme-vars($theme) {
    //default palette forground/background:
    $foreground-palette: map-get($theme, foreground);
    $background-palette: map-get($theme, background);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SCSS VARS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $primary: mat-color(map-get($theme, primary));
    $accent: mat-color(map-get($theme, accent));
    $warn: mat-color(map-get($theme, warn));

    $base: mat-color($foreground-palette, base);
    $divider: mat-color($foreground-palette, divider);
    $dividers: mat-color($foreground-palette, dividers);
    $disabled: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled);
    $disabled-button: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled-button);
    $disabled-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled-text);
    $hint-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, hint-text);
    $secondary-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, secondary-text);
    $icon: mat-color($foreground-palette, icon);
    $icons: mat-color($foreground-palette, icons);
    $text: mat-color($foreground-palette, text);
    $slider-off: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-off);
    $slider-off-active: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-off-active);

    $status-bar: mat-color($background-palette, status-bar);
    $app-bar: mat-color($background-palette, app-bar);
    $background: mat-color($background-palette, background);
    $hover: mat-color($background-palette, hover);
    $card: mat-color($background-palette, card);
    $dialog: mat-color($background-palette, dialog);
    $disabled-button: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-button);
    $raised-button: mat-color($background-palette, raised-button);
    $focused-button: mat-color($background-palette, focused-button);
    $selected-button: mat-color($background-palette, selected-button);
    $selected-disabled-button: mat-color($background-palette, selected-disabled-button);
    $disabled-button-toggle: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-button-toggle);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CSS VARS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////


    --primary-color: #{$primary};
    --accent-color: #{$accent};
    --warn-color: #{$warn};

    --base-color: #{$base};
    --divider-color: #{$divider};
    --dividers-color: #{$dividers};
    --disabled-color: #{$disabled};
    --disabled-button-color: #{$disabled-button};
    --disabled-text-color: #{$disabled-text};
    --hint-text-color: #{$hint-text};
    --secondary-text-color: #{$secondary-text};
    --icon-color: #{$icon};
    --icons-color: #{$icons};
    --text-color: #{$text};
    --slider-off-color: #{$slider-off};
    --slider-off-active-color: #{$slider-off-active};

    --status-bar-color: #{$status-bar};
    --app-bar-color: #{$app-bar};
    --background-color: #{$background};
    --hover-color: #{$hover};
    --card-color: #{$card};
    --dialog-color: #{$dialog};
    --disabled-button-color: #{$disabled-button};
    --raised-button-color: #{$raised-button};
    --focused-button-color: #{$focused-button};
    --selected-button-color: #{$selected-button};
    --selected-disabled-button-color: #{$selected-disabled-button};
    --disabled-button-toggle-color: #{$disabled-button-toggle};
}
```

It basically extracts colors from the angular theme and saves them in SCSS and CSS variables.

Everything works so far, but after updating some dependencies, I get a weird error that I don't know where it is coming from, but I know how to  workaround.

As you can see, if I call the page in Chrome and inspect the element that suddenly loses its color, then inspect it and view the styles, the CSS variable is crossed out (meaning it is overridden AFAIK).

[image: Chrome having error]

Now when I create a fake variable before the real variable like so (only part of the snippet):

```
  --primary-color-throwaway: #{$primary};
  --primary-color: #{$primary};
  --accent-color: #{$accent};
  --warn-color: #{$warn};

  --base-color: #{$base};
```

The color comes back and the inspection shows, that it now overrides the throwaway variable and not the real one like this:

[image]

#### Why does this happen?

Also, another variable has the same issue, but can't be fixed with this workaround:

```
--disabled-button-color: #{$disabled-button};
```

#### Edit

Here is the code where I use this mixin:

```
.dark-theme {
    @import "themes/dark-theme";
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
    @include generate-theme-vars($dark-theme);
}
```

themes/dark-theme:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();


$dark-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-green);
$dark-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$dark-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);

$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme(
    $dark-theme-primary,
    $dark-theme-accent,
    $dark-theme-warn
);

@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
```

Comment: How and where do you initiate the mixin?

Comment: @anderssonola I have added the code where it is used